# Windows 8: should I install programs to «secure location» (path)? What kind of programs? What happens if I do not

Tags: windows-8, security, path

Extracted from the *"Release Notes"* of **RealVNC Server v5.1.0** :

> «FIXED: Key combinations such as Alt+Tab are now supported for
>   connections to Windows 8 computers. Note VNC Server must be installed
>   to a **secure location** such as C:\Program Files. »

Coming from older Windows versions, I always use to install my programs at plain "*C:\*", like:

```
c:\RealVNC
```

Should I change my behavior when installing programs in **Windows 8** so my programs go to that path the operating system calls **"secure location"**?
How can I know **what paths are included** in that *"secure location"*?
Can I create my **custom** own *"secure location"*?
What **kind of programs** should be installed in a *secure location*? For example, I often use:

- Bitvise SSH Server
- RealVNC Server
- TeamViewer
- NMap
- CygWin

... is there a reason for that programs to requiere a *secure location*? What could happen if they are installed on something like **plain "C:\MyProgram"**?

Comment: We can't tell you what they mean by a "secure location" they likely used "secure" in the place of "protected" which is really what that location is. Protected locations are locations that require elevated user permissions to read and write. Unless its within your user directory Windows Vista and later will treat a directory as protected. You should install to Program Files and store user data in the proper user profile directory.  A user by default does not have acecss to write to `C:\MyProgram` just keep that in mind

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound, for answering, but I have just checked to enter `C:\MyProgram` (for a real test: `C:\Bitvise SSH Server`) using another user, and he has no problems to write into.

Comment: If the process permissions were elevated by an Administrator account then it wouldn't be a problem.  You can write to any directory provided the user elevates the permissions of the process.  **This entire process is well documented by Microsoft**